# what should be the settings in info plist for receiving string using airdrop

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc, airdrop, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I want to send one string using airdrop. I researched out but I am not able to clearly get what should I keep in info plist or what should be the exact settings so when that string is received, on accepting it opens my application. I am using uiactivityviewcontroller for sending string using airdrop, it arrives but there is no option of my application in the open pop up on accepting. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually only wanted to share string so in array I added a string object and passed that array in activity type. In info I did the following settings

1) Documents Types
Name : String
Types : public.data

Additional document type properties
CFBundleTypeRole : Array

2) Exported UTIs
Description : receive string(did not effect)
Identifier : com.appname.str
Conforms To : public.data

Additional exported UTI properties
1) UTTypeTagSpecification : Array

3) Imported UTIs
Description : Receive string
Identifier : text file
Conforms to : public.data

Additional imported UTI properties
1) UTTypeTagSpecification : Array

I researched many places and mostly found Document type and exported UTI Types are important.

Also found the below turtorials very helpful
1) http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-airdrop-programming-tutorial/
2) https://engineering.eventbrite.com/setting-the-title-of-airdrop-shares-under-ios-7/